# Sitecore Email Campaign Manager and MTA Logs

Tags: sitecore, ecm

I'm using Email Campaign Manager version v2.1 rev 140214 along with Sitecore v6.6 to send email. The instance is configured to send email via Sitecore's  MTA service.

Everything works most of the time, but intermittently email does not get sent even though in the Sitecore logs the message is flagged as processed and finished.

```
ManagedPoolThread #3 16:02:50 INFO  Job started: Sending message      (82DA24E91D714756AC0173B590BF0B27)
ManagedPoolThread #3 16:02:50 INFO  EmailCampaign: Dispatch Message ( xxx ): Started
ManagedPoolThread #3 16:03:20 INFO  EmailCampaign: 'xxx': 86 recipients are added to the queue.
ManagedPoolThread #3 16:03:40 INFO  EmailCampaign: Message 'xxx':
Recipients processed: 86.
Generate: min: 00:00:00.0312000; avg: 00:00:00.1382235; max: 00:00:00.3900007; total: 00:00:11.8872213.
Send: min: 00:00:00.8424014; avg: 00:00:00.9278388; max: 00:00:01.9344034; total: 00:01:19.7941399.
Process: min: 00:00:00.9048016; avg: 00:00:01.0660623; max: 00:00:02.3244041; total: 00:01:31.6813612.
ManagedPoolThread #3 16:03:40 INFO  EmailCampaign: Dispatch Message (xxx): Finished
ManagedPoolThread #3 16:03:40 INFO  Job ended: Sending message (82DA24E91D714756AC0173B590BF0B27) (units processed: )
```

So I'm thinking there's something going wrong connecting to the MTA service or within the MTA service itself.

Are there any logs that I can look at to tell me exactly what is happening after the email is processed?

Is the feedback only limited to bounced messages/status notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get more information on the messages sent via the MTA:

Click on the test connection button on the email campaign manager item. Once connected, make a note of the SMTP server you are connecting to.

Contact sitecore support and they will examine the logs on the SMTP server.